# Complex bin packing 2d in python

Tags: python, bin, texture2d, packing, bin-packing

im having some trouble with 2d bin packing and cant seem to get the code to work. In this case im using the input:

200x200x10

100x100x2

50x50x1

When starting the last piece in the sorted list of blocks (50x50) the packer identifies the correct node with a width of 100 and a height of 300, but it has the incorrect starting root at 700 instead of 600. I assume that it has something to do with the previous block being added at that root.

Data of the last node being found:

Width Root: 100

Height Root: 300

X Root: 700

Y Root: 300

The image shows the outline of the node size in red and the X root value of the last node added.

Would love some input if anyone can see some clear misstakes!

[Image Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C9o3.png)

The code is based on https://codeincomplete.com/articles/bin-packing/

```
class Block():
    def __init__(self, w : int, h : int) -> None:
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.fit = None

class Node():
    def __init__(self, x : int, y : int, w : int, h : int) -> None:
        self.used = False
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self.down = None
        self.right = None

class Packer():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.root = None
        self.blocks = None

    def fit(self, blocks : list[Block]) -> None:
        self.blocks = blocks
        self.root = Node(0, 0, self.blocks[0].w, self.blocks[0].h)
        for b in self.blocks:
            
            node = self.find_node(self.root, b.w, b.h)
            if node:
                
                b.fit = self.split_node(node, b.w, b.h)
            else:
                b.fit = self.grow_node(b.w, b.h)

    def find_node(self, root : Node, w : int, h : int) -> Node:
        if root.used:
            return self.find_node(root.right, w, h) or self.find_node(root.down, w, h)
        elif w <= root.w and h <= root.h:
            return root
        else:
            return None
    
    def split_node(self, node : Node, w : int, h : int) -> Node:
        node.used = True
        node.down = Node(node.x, node.y + h, node.w, node.h - h)
        node.right = Node(node.x + w, node.y, node.w - w, h)
        return node

    def grow_node(self, w : int, h : int) -> Node:
        can_grow_down = w <= self.root.w
        can_grow_right = w <= self.root.h

        should_grow_right = can_grow_right and self.root.h >= self.root.w + w
        should_grow_down = can_grow_down and self.root.w >= self.root.h + h

        if should_grow_right:
            return self.grow_right(w, h)
        elif should_grow_down:
            return self.grow_down(w, h)
        elif can_grow_right:
            return self.grow_right(w, h)
        elif can_grow_down:
            return self.grow_down(w, h)
        else:
            return None

    def grow_right(self, w : int, h : int) -> Node:
        new_node = Node(0, 0, self.root.w + w, self.root.h)
        new_node.used = True
        new_node.down = self.root
        new_node.right = Node(self.root.w, 0, w, self.root.h)
        self.root = new_node

        node = self.find_node(self.root, w, h)

        if node:
            return self.split_node(node, w, h)
        else:
            return None
    
    def grow_down(self, w : int, h : int) -> Node:
        new_node = Node(0, 0, self.root.w, self.root.h + h)
        new_node.used = True
        new_node.down = Node(0, self.root.h, self.root.w, h)
        new_node.right = self.root
        self.root = new_node

        node = self.find_node(self.root, w, h)

        if node:
            return self.split_node(node, w, h)
        else:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by fixing a typo. Should work fine now for complex 2d bin packing!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).